# hsqldb indexOutOfBoundException

Tags: postgresql, hsqldb, indexoutofboundsexception

I have a relation, which has about 5000 records.

**PROBLEM**:

Suppose I have 1 record:

> name : 'adam'   , family : 'white'  , data:'003*12/12/12' ,
>   father:'jack'

when I search:

```
select * from tbl_r1 where 1=1 and father='adam';//return 0 record
```

or

```
select * from tbl_r1 where 1=1 and father='jack';//return 1 record
```

it works well, but:

```
select * from tbl_r1 where 1=1 and father='adam' and     
CONVERT(substring(data from 1 for 3),BigInt)= 3;
```

it throws exception "

> StringIndexOutOfBoundsException :-7" or -80

and so on

this query is ok in postgresql because I filtered by father name...

Answer (score 0):

This works fine with the latest version of HSQLDB (2.3.3).

Comment: i switched to new version but it throws new exception 
java.sql.SQLDataException: data exception: invalid character value for cast

Comment: The `substring(data from 1 for 3)` must contain digits only. The exception is thrown because in some row this substring contains other characters as well..

Comment: yeah u right ,  but unblivable issue is that there is no record by this filter father = 'adam'

Comment: i think  , i have to search in my app ,thx fredt  for quick response